# Pen-pal’ing in 21st century

Tags: communication

Last night, my friend and I had the idea of setting up his daughter and mine as pen pals. He lives in Calgary, Canada, I live in Hong Kong. His daughter is 7, mine is 9; they have never met.

Is pen-pal’ing still a thing nowadays?

Some of the reasons why I want my daughter to have a penpal:

- to practice her English;
- to learn about the world outside Hong Kong;
- to have a “ready” friend when I eventually move back to Canada; this might make her more enthusiastic about moving to Canada, too.

How do I explain to my daughter why she should write instead of just video chat over Zoom or whatever?

Is it still best done via snail mail? Or would e-mail be ok as a delivery mechanism? What if my daughter handwrites letters or draws pictures on paper, and then I scan them and e-mail them as attachments.

Comment: Hi there - this question doesn't really meet requirements here. I think you have articulated things you can try - so I'd suggest doing them. My youngest does all of them with different friends across the world.